# CodeIgniter getting Value from Database to display

Tags: codeigniter

**Error
----**

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_RETURN in C:\wamp\www\jobsite\application\models\model_users.php on line 71**

```
public function profile_data()
{
    $this->load->database();
    $query = $this->db->get('tbl_studentreg')  //tbl_studentreg is the table name
    return $query->result();                   // Line 71
}
```

**May I know how to fix it? thanks in advance.**

Comment: use any good php editor like netbeans or eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a semicolon here:

```
$query = $this->db->get('tbl_studentreg'); //semicolon added
```